# `[object: null prototype] { title: 'video', description: 'My video!!' } on nodejs - multer`

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

```
import routes from "./routes";
import multer from "multer";

const multerVideo = multer({ dest: "videos/" });

export const localsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
res.locals.siteName = "Webtube";
res.locals.routes = routes;
res.locals.user = {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    id: 1
}
next();
};


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export const uploadVideo = multerVideo.single("videoFile");

export const postupload = (req, res) => {
const { body } = req;
//To Do: Upload and save Video
console.log(body);
res.render("upload", { pageTitle: "upload" });
};

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
extends layouts/main

block content
    div.form_container
        form(action=`/videos${routes.upload}`, method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
            label(for="file") Video File
            input(type="file", id="file", name="videoFile", required=true, 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please fill out this field')", accept="video/*")
            input(type="text", placeholder="Title", name="title", required=true)
            textarea(name="description", placeholder="Description", required=true)
            input(type="submit", value="Upload Video")
```

I have tried to use multer but the result was just like this:
[object: null prototype] { title: 'video', description: 'My video!!' }
I wanna get video file name also but couldn't.
Is there any who know how to solve to problem?

Answer (score 0):

When using `.single(..)` `multer` will populate the `file`-property on the `req`-object, which will contain all the data/information you need. In your case (assuming that the `uploadVideo`-middleware is called before of course):

```
export const postupload = (req, res) => {
    const { file } = req;
    //To Do: Upload and save Video
    console.log(file.originalname);
    res.render("upload", { pageTitle: "upload" });
};
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) if you want to see all properties on the `file`-object.